# How to extract relations from parsed sentences

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

Natural language parsers (e.g. [Stanford parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml)) output the syntactic tree of a sentence and perhaps a list of POS-tagged words and a list of dependencies. For example for the sentence:

*Bell, based in Los Angeles, makes and distributes electronic, computer and building products.*

Stanford parser [correctly infers](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf) that the subject of "*makes*" is "*Bell*" and the object is "*products*" while "*electronic*", "*computer*", "*building*" are all modifiers of "*products*". Similarly with "*distributes*". A natural next step would be to use this information to construct a list of relations like this:

- Bell makes electronic products
- Bell makes computer products
- Bell makes building products
- Bell distributes electronic products

... and a couple more. More generally, I want a list of relations of the form:

subject - action - object

for the sake of concreteness let's assume that action can only be a single verb, subject - a noun and object - a noun with optional adjectives prepended. Obviously transformation from a parsed sentence to a set of such relations will be lossy but the result lends itself much more easily to further machine processing than a raw syntactic tree. I know how to extract these relations by hand when I see a parsed sentence, this question asks: **how to do this automatically?** Is there a known algorithm that does something similar? If not, how should I approach building one?

I'm not asking for a parser recommendation, this is a task **on top of parsing**. This task seems to me

1. very useful
2. not quite trivial
3. much simpler than parsing itself

and as such I would imagine people would have done it already many times. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything even close.

Comment: The Stanford parser *is* a library in a popular programming language. At least, I'm given to understand that Java is a popular programming language. If you want wrappers in other popular programming languages, there is a list on the [Stanford parser site](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Extensions). Also, if Python is on your popular list, see [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)

Comment: I'm already using both the Stanford parser and NLTK, this is a question about postprocessing outputs from the parser. Edited the question - hope it will make more sense now.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The problem is definitely non-trivial. The guideline against asking for tools is meant to prevent lazy questions and opinionated answers, not prevent people from finding tools for complex problems.

Comment: If the structure is that simple, why not brute-force it and just create all combinations? It's something that could be done with a simple visitor in any language, or with a syntax tree transformation using a parser tool (I think this is called tree rewriting). It doesn't have to be AI

Comment: Basically, yes, tree rewriting is what I'm doing. The problem is the rules for this particular rewriting are a bit more complicated than they usually are in the case of parsing programming languages. For example the comma between "electronic" and "computer" indicates conjunction whereas the comma before "based" has different meaning and needs a different rule. So it is not completely straightforward. but

Comment: I think you could get a lot of what you're wishing for with collapsed CC-processed dependencies. Try putting in your example sentence at the CoreNLP demo and look at the last visualization (labeled "collapsed CC-processed"): http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process

Comment: Still, I suspect that unlike parsing itself it is doable with a relatively short set of rules. Shame I phrased the question like I did and now no one is gonna answer. Would love to see what kinds of opinionated answers this question would attract.

Comment: Another thing you can try is OpenIE (http://openie.cs.washington.edu/), or even just simple [Semgrex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/semgrex/SemgrexPattern.html) rules (e.g., "{$}=verb ?>/advmod/ {}=adv >/nsubj(pass)?/ {}=subject >/prep-*/ {}=object" for "subject verbs prep object", or "{$}=verb >/.subj.*/ {}=subject >/.obj/ {}=object" for "subject verbs object".

Comment: Also, at the moderators, is it possible to have someone from the Stanford NLP group moderate the "stanford-nlp" tag (or at least help moderate)? This would allow us to reopen questions like these, once they are re-worded and we can give a meaningful answer to them.

Comment: Tried using dependencies as per Jon Gauthier's advice. Was able to build a script that does the right thing at least some of the time. It is not very robust because as a nlp noob I'm constantly discovering new cases that I need to cover. ReVerb from OpenIE looks perfect though, will see how it works in practice.